# GeometryRenderer Why render lines, but not Triangles

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

I am trying to proceduraly generate Cube with a GeometryRenderer. Why when GeometryRenderer.primitiveType is set to LineLoop, Lines or TriangleFan everything works, but with Triangles or TrianglesStrip draws absolutely nothing?

```
PhongMaterial { id: material; }

GeometryRenderer {
    id: renderer
    primitiveType: GeometryRenderer.LineLoop
    instanceCount: 1
    geometry: Geometry {
        attributes: [
            Attribute {
                name: defaultPositionAttributeName
                attributeType: Attribute.VertexAttribute
                vertexBaseType: Attribute.Float
                vertexSize: 3
                byteOffset: 0
                byteStride: 3 * 4
                count: 6
                buffer: Buffer {
                    type: Buffer.VertexBuffer
                    data: new Float32Array([
                                               // #1 triangle
                                               -0.9, -0.5, 0.0,
                                               -0.0, -0.5, 0.0,
                                               -0.45, 0.5, 0.0,
                                               // #2 triangle
                                               0.0, -0.5, 0.0,
                                               0.9, -0.5, 0.0,
                                               0.45, 0.5, 0.0,
                                           ])
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

Entity {
    components: [
        renderer,
        material
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I adapt your QML the following way then I can see two triangles:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
import Qt3D.Extras 2.0

Entity {
    id: root
    PhongMaterial { id: material; diffuse: Qt.rgba(0.8, 0., 0., 1.0) }
    GeometryRenderer {
        id: renderer
        primitiveType: GeometryRenderer.Triangles
        instanceCount: 1
        geometry: Geometry {
            Attribute {
                name: defaultPositionAttributeName
                attributeType: Attribute.VertexAttribute
                vertexBaseType: Attribute.Float
                vertexSize: 3
                byteOffset: 0
                byteStride: 3 * 4
                count: 6
                buffer: Buffer {
                    type: Buffer.VertexBuffer
                    data: new Float32Array([
                                    // #1 triangle
                                    -0.9, -0.5, 0.0,
                                    -0.0, -0.5, 0.0,
                                    -0.45, 0.5, 0.0,
                                    // #2 triangle
                                    0.0, -0.5, 0.0,
                                    0.9, -0.5, 0.0,
                                    0.45, 0.5, 0.0,
                                ])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    components: [ renderer, material ]
}
```

I suppose the error is related to the wrong hierarchy of GeometryRenderer and Entity.

To get correct lighting you need to give the GeometryRenderer the vertexNormals too.

**Edit:**

As it is a common question whether a `GeometryRenderer` always needs an `indexBuffer` for `primitiveType: Triangles`, `TriangleStrip`, and `TriangleFan`, I'll come up with a somewhat more detailed answer.

A `GeometryRenderer` of `primitiveType: Triangles` does **not** necessarily need an index array (I checked the source code of `Qt3D` as I was unsure).

The reason you are not seeing your triangles is: You are defining the vertices in the wrong order! Change the order of the vertices in the `vertexBuffer` so that every three consecutive vertices form a triangle when going **counterclockwise** around the triangle. The triangle normal will then point at you.

Or, have a look onto your Entity from the opposite direction: you'll see the two triangles.

When using huge buffers and you don't want to repeat large amounts of vertices for memory/efficiency reasons you'll definitely should consider using an `indexBuffer`.

Comment: Weird, I would have thought, that adding a note as component to an entity sets the entity as the node's parent.

Comment: AFAIK, the GeometryRenderer and the PhongMaterial need to be declared inside of an Entity. And that's what the original fragment is missing.